# Component ID - Red bullet shaped resistors

Tags: identification

I have a handful of red somewhat bullet shaped 67k 1% resistors that were in a box of assorted electronics components, probably 30 or 40 years old. I've never seen anything like them so I'm curious if someone else knows anything about them.
[image: 7 resistors on granite]

Comment: is there anything printed on the components?

Comment: I am curious to know how much they have changed over time. I have carbon composition resistors that have changed 30-40% over 40-50 years. I would hope that these would be much better.

Comment: "?"s for characters I can't make out
?AT?RES
EG?43
67k(ohm symbol)=1%

Comment: @Mattman944 66.9, 70.0, 70.1 and 70.2 for the 4 I just checked. There is one of 8 that is around 58 but the rest are spot on.

Comment: @Jonathan A detail fell to mind. That particular molded shape and the color red reminds me of IRC. Any way you can verify that? I am thinking of something like [these](https://www.ebay.com/itm/224792566934?hash=item3456ae5c96:g:zjsAAOSwaQZh41XO). Your shapes are different, though.

Comment: What country did these likely come from? They're not something I've seen. Companies like Tesla (Czechoslovakia) and Iskra (Yugoslavia) had some odd-looking parts, and being conglomerate SOEs, a ready internal market.